# SQL Server 2005 RIGHT OUTER JOIN not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, inner-join, outer-join

I'm looking up access logs for specific courses.  I need to show all the courses even if they don't exist in the logs table.  Hence the outer join.... but after trying (presumably) all of the variations of `LEFT OUTER`, `RIGHT OUTER`, `INNER` and placement of the tables within the SQL code, I couldn't get my result.

Here's what I am running:

```
SELECT   (a.first_name+' '+a.last_name) instructor,
            c.course_id,
            COUNT(l.access_date) course_logins,
            a.logins system_logins,
            MAX(l.access_date) last_course_login,
            a.last_login last_system_login
FROM       lsn_logs l RIGHT OUTER JOIN courses c ON l.course_id = c.course_id,
            accounts a
WHERE     l.object_id = 'LOGIN' 
            AND c.course_type = 'COURSE' 
            AND c.course_id NOT LIKE '%TEST%' 
            AND a.account_rights > 2
            AND l.user_id = a.username
            AND ((a.first_name+' '+a.last_name) = c.instructor)
GROUP BY    c.course_id, 
            a.first_name, 
            a.last_name,
            a.last_login,
            a.logins,
            c.instructor
ORDER BY    a.last_name,
            a.first_name,
            c.course_id,
            course_logins DESC
```

Is it something in the `WHERE` clause that's preventing me from getting course_id's that don't exist in lsn_logs?  Is it the way I'm joining the tables?

Again, in short, I want all course_id's regardless of their existence in lsn_logs.

Comment: Should you maybe be looking at doing a left join from courses to lsn_logs?

Comment: You are joining accounts with `lsn_logs`. What account should be returned if there is no log_entry for a given course?

Comment: @quassnoi - the instructor of the course

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: OK, and what if there are more than one log entry for a course with different `l.user_id`? Which account should be returned then?

Comment: @quassnoi - the sum/max & group by coupled with ((a.first_name+' '+a.last_name) = c.instructor) ensures that only the instructor's aggregates are tracked

Comment: @Cheese: do I understand correctly that you only want to aggregate the instructor's logs?

Comment: @Q - yes, and also show where the instructors have courses with no access logged yet (the absence of aggregates? whats the word for that?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT...    
FROM courses c
     INNER JOIN accounts a
        ON (a.first_name+' '+a.last_name) = c.instructor
     LEFT OUTER JOIN lsn_logs l
        ON l.course_id = c.course_id
        AND l.user_id = a.username
        AND l.object_id = 'LOGIN' 
WHERE c.course_type = 'COURSE'  
    AND c.course_id NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
    AND a.account_rights > 2 
    AND a.logins > 0 
GROUP BY...
ORDER BY...
```

Comment: nice - this works the same as mine, but eliminates all the null checking

Comment: your solution returns 1386 and mine returns 1358... i gotta investigate that

Answer (score 8):

> Is it something in the WHERE clause that's preventing me from getting course_id's that don't exist in lsn_logs?

Yes, it is.

You use equality conditions in your `WHERE` clause that effectively filter out the `NULL` rows generated by the `OUTER JOIN`.

**Update:**

```
SELECT  c.instructor,
        c.course_id,
        l.course_logins,
        a.logins system_logins,
        l.last_course_login,
        a.last_login last_system_login
FROM    courses с
JOIN    accounts a
ON      a.first_name + ' ' + a.last_name = c.instructor
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COALESCE(COUNT(access_date), 0) course_logins,
                MAX(access_date) last_course_login
        FROM    lsn_logs l
        WHERE   l.object_id = 'LOGIN'
                AND l.course_id = c.course_id
                AND l.user_id = a.username
        ) l
WHERE   c.course_type = 'COURSE' 
        AND c.course_id NOT LIKE '%TEST%' 
        AND a.account_rights > 2
ORDER BY
        a.last_name,
        a.first_name,
        c.course_id,
        course_logins DESC
```

Comment: thats what i figured... i think joe r's and/or andomars answer might work, but thanks for the clarification

Comment: @cheese: could you please answer the question in my comment to your post?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Quassnoi's good answer, for the outer join to work you could change:

```
AND l.user_id = a.username
```

To:

```
AND (l.user_id is null OR l.user_id = a.username)
```

Comment: the accounts and courses tables will always have records that match, but the lsn_logs will be empty for some courses and/or accounts

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: Answer edited so it just checks for null on the lsn_logs table

Comment: also this - (l.object_id IS NULL OR l.object_id = 'LOGIN')... mention something about null checks in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server 2005 RIGHT OUTER JOIN certainly works! :)

What about the following (I've made some assumptions)?:

remove

```
AND l.user_id = a.username
```

and change the joins to

```
dbo.courses c
LEFT OUTER JOIN lsn_logs l
ON c.course_id = l.course_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts a
ON l.user_id = a.username
```

and add some null checks for lsn_logs and accounts fields, such as:

```
(l.object_id IS NULL OR l.object_id = 'LOGIN')
```

Comment: By the way, you have a very disturbing photo! :)

Comment: its disturbing in a good way though... thanks for the suggestion, i think your double outer join might work

Comment: still same result set... i see where you were going with this though

Comment: You'd also need null checks on, e.g. - (l.object_id is null OR l.object_id = 'LOGIN')

Comment: ya i didn't think of that, and thats what it was

Comment: add something about null checks to your answer

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working

The null checks that Joe R suggested took care of the problem that Quassnoi mentioned

```
SELECT   (a.first_name+' '+a.last_name) instructor,
            c.course_id,
            COUNT(l.access_date) course_logins,
            a.logins system_logins,
            MAX(l.access_date) last_course_login,
            a.last_login last_system_login
FROM       lsn_logs l RIGHT OUTER JOIN courses c ON l.course_id = c.course_id,
            accounts a
WHERE     (l.object_id IS NULL OR l.object_id = 'LOGIN') 
            AND c.course_type = 'COURSE' 
            AND c.course_id NOT LIKE '%TEST%' 
            AND a.account_rights > 2
            AND (l.user_id = a.username OR l.user_id IS NULL)
            AND ((a.first_name+' '+a.last_name) = c.instructor)
            AND a.logins > 0
GROUP BY    c.course_id, 
            a.first_name, 
            a.last_name,
            a.last_login,
            a.logins,
            c.instructor
ORDER BY    a.last_name,
            a.first_name,
            c.course_id,
            course_logins DESC
```

Comment: btw - there is probably a better way to do this all within the `FROM` section.... please post any modifications

Comment: this throws and error "sqlclient data provider error number 8153" but still returns the results.... gotta look into that